# how to connect dynamics AX 2009 and visual studio 2008

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2008, connection, dynamics-ax-2009

where can i find a guid what to install for developing in AX and visual studio?

I have AX 2009 and Visual Studio 2008 but I am not able to connect them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For most AX 2009 development, you use the integrated development environment called MorphX. Take a look at [Walkthrough: Getting Started with Customizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa660163(v=ax.50)) to learn more about it.

Some AX 2009 customizations require Visual Studio, most notable customizations of SSRS reports. There is also development done in Visual Studio for integration scenarios where the Business Connector component of AX 2009 can be used. Take a look at [Creating Reports for Microsoft Dynamics AX in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/cc653472(v=ax.50)) and [.NET Business Connector Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsax-2009/developer/aa659581(v=ax.50)) to learn more.

To learn about installing the necessary components, take a look at the [installation guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2960), especially the "Install development components" part.